# Share rooted Android ethernet connection to another ethernet only device. Is it possible?

Tags: networking, vpn, ethernet, android, tethering

I have a rooted Android device running a VPN and connected to my internet router via an ethernet adapter.

My question is: is it possible to share this connection to an ethernet only device adding a second ethernet adapter to the Android one?

I've tried with ethernet tethering but, every time I enable it, it only allows me to share the connection via Wi-Fi creating an hotspot and I'm not able to figure out how to force Android to use the second ethernet connection instead.

My ultimate goal is to be able to let my ethernet only device to connect to the internet using the VPN while using a wired only solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just watched a YouTube vid the otber day where the guy made the point that a phone being used as a bridge or hotspot may have a VPN on it, but the pass through data does not use the VPN at all. Just a thought. I may be way off. Meh. First day here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).